# Do I need to repeat 'of the'?

Tags: possessives

Let us suppose you are a repairman.

Each evening you must check **the** condition **of the** fireplace **and of the** boiler?

Answer (score -1):

> Each evening you must check the condition of the fireplace and of the boiler.

The example sentence is perfectly correct and natural. One could instead say:

> Each evening you must check the condition of the fireplace and  boiler.

The meaning might be unchanged, but this form suggests that "the fireplace and  boiler" are in some way a unit, and would be checked together. The original sentence does not suggest that, although it does not indicate that they are separate either. It says nothing about that, one way or the other.  If he two are essentially separate, the original sentence is more natural, although the shorter one is not wrong.

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain the perceived problem with this answer, so that I can address it and perhaps improve the answer, or future answers?

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation!
BTW: I think that the downvote was because of the few spelling errors (“If he two”, alhtoguh), not because of the content.